# How can I reduce a dimension of a numpy array, then trim some from the end?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(6, 100, 161)`. I want to convert it to `(600, 161)` and then trim 16 from the end, so it's `(584, 161)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call reshape followed by slicing

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((6,100,161))

b = a.reshape(600,161)[:-16,:]

b.shape

out: (584,161)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.ones((6,100,161))
>>> x = x.reshape((-1, 161))
>>> x = x[:584, :]
>>> x.shape
(584, 161)
```

Here `-1` works like this:

If the original shape was (x, y, z)

then if you write `reshape(-1, z)`

It infers that you want to dimensions, as you have given two numbers `-1` and `z`, but you have specified size for only 1 dimension (i.e. `z`), so it infers the other size must be all that remains.

So total number of elements `x * y * z`, now after reshaping the number of elements must be same. You have specified you want `z` number of columns, so the number of rows must be `x * y * z / z == x * y`. `-1` facilitates this.

For example:

```
>>> x = np.ones((3,4,3))
# number of elements = 3 * 4 * 3 == 36
>>> y = x.reshape(9, -1)
# you say you want 9 rows, so remaining elements 
# would be, 36 / 9 == 4, so no. of cols == 4
>>> y.shape
(9, 4)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `(-1, 161)` does please?

Comment: `x[:584, 161]` will throw an error. Should either be `x[:584, :161]` or `x[:584, :]`